# Rstudio exits debug mode when an error occurs

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the debug tool in Rstudio to execute a function line by line. However, Rstudio will exit debug mode whenever an error occurs, before I had time to save several important variables to the global environment. Is there a way to avoid this and stay in the debugging environment once an error occurs?

To replicate this:

```
t.f <- function(x) {
  y <- sample(1:2000, 10)
  print(x)
  rm(x)
  print(x)
  return(y)
}
debug(t.f)
t.f(1)
```

after executing the line `print(x)`, which will throw an error because `x` does not exist anymore, the debugger will quit. Is it possible to prevent this behavior?

Comment: It's not an [tag:rstudio] thing, it's an [tag:r] thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the R debugger is somewhat limited and set in its ways (no flame wars). Hadley's [Advanced R - Debugging](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html) and specifically 22.4.2.2 *Alternatives* suggests a few things, including `options(error=recover)`, which I've never been successful at mastering ... nor am I positive that it'll solve this problem.